# Covalent Dynamic Forms get the inserted data

Tags: angular, angular-material2, teradata-covalent

I'm using Dynamic Forms in an Angular project using [Teradata Colvalent](https://github.com/Teradata/covalent), this is the data that I ask to the user:

```ts
public inputElements: ITdDynamicElementConfig[] = [
  {
    name: 'Risposta',
    label: 'Risposta alla domanda',
    type: TdDynamicElement.Input,
    required: true,
    default: this.selectedIntent.IntentDataRecord.Answer,
    flex: 100
  },
  {
    name: 'Descrizione',
    type: TdDynamicElement.Input,
    required: true,
    default: this.selectedIntent.IntentDataRecord.Description,
    flex: 100
  },
  {
    name: 'Esempi',
    type: TdDynamicElement.Input,
    required: true,
    default: this.selectedIntent.IntentDataRecord.Examples,
    flex: 50
  },
  {
    name: 'Suggerimenti',
    type: TdDynamicElement.Input,
    required: true,
    default: this.selectedIntent.IntentDataRecord.Hint,
    flex: 50
  }
];
```

And here I use it into the HTML template:

```html
<td-dynamic-forms [elements]="this.inputElements">
      <ng-template let-element ngFor [ngForOf]="this.inputElements">
        <ng-template let-control="formControl" [tdDynamicFormsError]="element.name">
          <span *ngIf="control.touched || !control.pristine">
            <span *ngIf="control.hasError('minlength')">Min length value: {{element.minLength}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="control.hasError('maxlength')">Max length value: {{element.minLength}}</span>
          </span>
        </ng-template>
      </ng-template>
    </td-dynamic-forms>
```

Is there a way to retrieve the data inserted from the user so I can use it in my component (for example after a button is clicked)?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the properties shown in [document](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/dynamic-forms). It mentions about **value property**

> value: any
>
> Getter property for [value] of dynamic [FormGroup].

To access value from dynamic form component, use **ViewChild** as shown below in your component class

```
@ViewChild(TdDynamicFormsComponent) formValues: TdDynamicFormsComponent;
```

Now you can access all field values using **formValues.value**, which will be an JSON.

Comment: use Reactive Form and use FormArray

Comment: Yes, in the end I used that